# Yup validation yup string schema is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup

I've got a type error in tsx for either the item or options value in the phone numbers validation. Yup is throwing a type error saying argument of type

> '(_item: any, options: {    path: string;}) =>
> yup.StringSchema' is not assignable to parameter of type
> '(value: string) => Schema'.

Here is my code:

```
export const schema = yup.object().shape({
  contactID: yup.string().required('Please select an option').nullable(),
  firstName: yup.string().when('contactID', {
    is: 'other',
    then: yup.string().required('First Name is required').nullable(),
    otherwise: yup.string().nullable(),
  }),
  lastName: yup.string().when('contactID', {
    is: 'other',
    then: yup.string().required('Last Name is required').nullable(),
    otherwise: yup.string().nullable(),
  }),
  phoneNumber: yup.array().of(
    yup.object().shape({
      phoneNumber: yup.lazy((item: any, options: { path: string }) => {
        if (options.path === 'insuredContactInformation.phoneNumber[0].phoneNumber') {
          return phoneValidation(true).required('Phone Number is required');
        } else return phoneValidation(true);
      }),
      phoneType: yup.string().nullable()
    })
  ),
});
```

This is the error

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by changing the PropTypes type when passed to the component. Instead of **object**, i pass **func**:

```
// Proptypes
BrandForm.propTypes = {
  t: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  onFormSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  validationSchema: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

And when pass to the component this way:

```
  <BrandForm
      validationSchema={() => addNewBrandSchema(language)}
  />
```